# SOQL Query to get Accounts that have been refreshed since x time

Tags: soql, query, account, sobject, lastmodifieddate

I have a connected app that will pull data from a salesforce Object. In order to do so,  am executing the following query (and sending it through the REST API as form-url-encoded):

```
SELECT Name,Id,Type FROM Account WHERE Type='Customer'
```

When executed, it gives me the count of the objects that the query returned, as well as such objects. Since I am doing some synchronization amongst systems, I wanted to know if it was possible to put a constraint in the query such as this:

```
SELECT Name,Id,Type FROM Account WHERE Type='Customer' AND Update_At=CURDATE()
```

`CURDATE()` does not necessarily have to be a function native to SOQL (I can just pass a date/timestamp/etc) and the operand `=` can be `<=` and `>=` as well so I can get the SObjects that match that timeframe.

I am merely interested in getting just the Accounts who have been updated since x date to be concise. I know about the `If-Modified-Since` header, which will return (or not) the object provided the ID if the SObject has been modified since the provided date. This is not a solution for me, since I would have to do n requests + 1 just to check if all the accounts have been updated (or is this the actual way of doing it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Some example formats for an exact date would be

```
LastModifiedDate >= 2016-10-01
LastModifiedDate = YESTERDAY
SystemModStamp = TODAY
```

Or you can use `Date Literals`, for example:

```
SystemModStamp = LAST_N_DAYS:25
LastModifiedDate < LAST_30_DAYS
SystemModStamp = LAST_MONTH
```

**Field**

In terms of which field to look at, both `SystemModStamp` and `LastModifiedDate` give you info about when the record was last modified. See: [When is SystemModStamp different from LastModifiedDate?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=When-is-SystemModStamp-different-from-LastModifiedDate&language=en_US)

> LastModifiedDate is the date and time when a record was last modified by a user, and SystemModstamp is the date and time when a record was last modified by a user or by an automated process (such as a trigger). In this context, "trigger" refers to Salesforce code that runs to implement standard functionality, rather than an "Apex trigger".

**Value**

In terms of the filter value itself, have a read of [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), which has plenty of useful info on this subject.

> **Format**
> Date only
>
> **Format Syntax**
> YYYY-MM-DD
>
> **Example**
> 1999-01-01
>
> ---
>
> **Format**
> Date, time, and time zone offset
>
> **Format Syntax**
> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm
> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm
> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
>
> **Example**
> 1999-01-01T23:01:01+01:00
> 1999-01-01T23:01:01-08:00
> 1999-01-01T23:01:01Z

Comment: Is `DateField__c` the "last updated" date? As in, if I update an Accounts Object, this field will be updated?

Comment: That field would be `LastModifiedDate`, or you may be interested in `SystemModStamp`.

Comment: Do you happen to know 1. The date format? 2. A link where can I look further into this? Many thanks!

Comment: Also, will my final query be the following then? `SELECT Name,Id,Type FROM Account WHERE Type='Customer' AND LastModifiedDate < 2016-11-01` or can `LAST_N_DAYS:25` work for LastModifiedDate as well?

Comment: @JackGal I added some links if you go the query route. If you want records modified since October 1, for example, you would do `AND LastModifiedDate > 2016-10-01`, or you could do the last 30 days using `LastModifiedDate = LAST_30_DAYS`. There are many `Date Literal` options available.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will check it out ASAP. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[getUpdated()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getupdated.htm) is the preferred way to do mirroring, if you're calling the SOAP API, or [SObject Get Updated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm) if you're using the REST API. This API gives you records updated since X time, *and* even tells you records that are "in-flight" but haven't been committed yet. This allows you to make sure that you don't miss records that were in-flight since the last check. You can also use [date literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), such as "today", but getUpdated allows much more granular replication. There's also a similar function to find records that have been deleted (hard or soft) since the last replication.

When using the REST API, your request will look like this:

```
/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Account/updated/​​​?start=2013-05-06T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&end=2013-05-10T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00
```

Where start and end are the date ranges you want to cover. You'll get back a result that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "ids" : 
    [ 
        "001D0000008pQR5IAM", 
        "001D0000008pQRGIA2", 
        "001D0000008pQRFIA2"
    ],
    "latestDateCovered" : "2013-05-08T21:20:00.000+0000" 
}
```

Comment: Is there such functionality for REST? I would use SOAP but my hands are tied to REST as of now... many thanks for your response

Comment: @JackGal Yes, sorry, I forgot about the REST version. I've added a link for you.